# Runtime error 9 "Subscript out o range" in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I get "runtime error 9. subscript out of range" every time I run code in VBA Excel.
[A line gets highlighted when I click on debug as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfuSd.jpg)

Here is the code

```
 tickerURL = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" & Symbols & _
    "?period1=" & startDate & _
    "&period2=" & endDate & _
    "&interval=" & period & "&events=history" & "&crumb=" & crumb
           
Set objRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
With objRequest
    .Open "GET", tickerURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Cookie", cookie
    .send
    .waitForResponse
    resultFromYahoo = .ResponseText
End With

nColumns = 6
csv_rows() = Split(resultFromYahoo, Chr(10))
csv_rows = Filter(csv_rows, csv_rows(0), False)

ReDim resultArray(0 To UBound(csv_rows), 0 To nColumns) As Variant
 
For iRows = LBound(csv_rows) To UBound(csv_rows)
    CSV_Fields = Split(csv_rows(iRows), ",")
    If UBound(CSV_Fields) > nColumns Then
        nColumns = UBound(CSV_Fields)
        ReDim Preserve resultArray(0 To UBound(csv_rows), 0 To nColumns) As Variant
    End If

    For iCols = LBound(CSV_Fields) To UBound(CSV_Fields)
        If IsNumeric(CSV_Fields(iCols)) Then
            resultArray(iRows, iCols) = Val(CSV_Fields(iCols))
        ElseIf IsDate(CSV_Fields(iCols)) Then
            resultArray(iRows, iCols) = CDate(CSV_Fields(iCols))
        Else
            resultArray(iRows, iCols) = CStr(CSV_Fields(iCols))
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code as text (no screenshots of code).

Comment: If the `Filter` doesn't match anything, you're trying to redim the first dimension as `0 to -1` and you can't do that.